# Why is CompletableFuture.supplyAsync succeeding a random number of times?

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, completable-future

I'm new to both lambdas and asynchronous code in Java 8. I keep getting some weird results...

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String test = "Test_" + i;
            final int a = i;

            CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doPost(test));
            cf.thenRun(() -> System.out.println(a)) ;
        }
    }

    private static boolean doPost(String t) {
        System.out.println(t);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The actual code is a lot longer, as the `doPost` method will post some data to a web service. However, I'm able to replicate my issue with this bare-bones code.

I want to have the `doPost` method execute 100 times, but asynchronously for performance reasons (in order to push data to the web service faster than doing 100 synchronous calls would be).

In the code above, the ´doPost´ method is run a random amount of times, but always no more than 20-25 times. There are no exceptions thrown. It seems that either some thread handling mechanism is silently refusing to create new threads and execute their code, or the threads are silently crashing without crashing the program.

I also have an issue where, if I add more functionality to the `doPost` method than shown above, it reaches a point where the method simply silently breaks. I've tried adding a `System.out.println("test")` right before the return statement in that case, but it is never called. The loop which loops 100 times does run 100 iterations though.

This behaviour is confusing, to say the least.

What am I missing? Why is the function supplied as an argument to `supplyAsync` run a seemingly random number of times?

*EDIT: Just wanted to point out that the situation is not exactly the same as in the question this was marked as a possible duplicate of, as that question dealt with arbitrarily deeply nested futures, and this one deals with parallell ones. However, the reason why they are failing is virtually identical. The cases seem distinct enough to merit separate questions to me, but others might disagree...*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Futures not executing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342302/nested-futures-not-executing)

Comment: Your `main` method does not wait for the futures to complete, so the JVM exits before your tasks finish their execution.

Comment: Thanks @DidierL - seems obvious now that you mention it. I'm used to asynchronous code, but in the context of Javascript, which has an event loop. So in Java, a kind of reference counting technique is required then? In this case, since the async stuff is done right in main(), making a new CompletableFuture using .allOf() and doing a .get() on that is probably sufficient; but as I understand it, .get() is blocking, so if one wanted to avoid blocking, a kind of reference counting technique should solve the issue.

Comment: @JoeDyndale When waiting for *all* the requests to complete (ie. before the program ends), blocking on any request (in any order) is OK. The others will still run as needed and this is no different than join'ing on N created threads that must complete before continuing more work. If there is more async work that needs to be done *without* a unified join, then this should be "pipelined" as a result of previous work - that does not sound like the case here.

Comment: There is no issue with blocking per se, especially since your main thread has nothing else to do, and you want it to wait until your futures complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `CompletableFuture` uses own *ForkJoinPool.commonPool()* (see [`CompletableFuture`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#l2129) implementation). And this default pool creates only *daemon* threads, e.g. they won't block the main application from terminating if they still alive.

You have the following choices:

1. Collect all `CompletionStage` to some array and then make [`java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)`.toCompletableFuture().join()` - this will guarantee all the stages are completed before going after *join()*
2. Use **Async* operations with your own thread pool which contains only *non-daemon* threads, like in the following example:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, r -> {
           Thread t = new Thread(r);
           t.setDaemon(false); // must be not daemon
           return t;
       });

       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           final int a = i;

           // the operation must be Async with our thread pool
           CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doPost(a), pool);
           cf.thenRun(() -> System.out.printf("%s: Run_%s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), a));
       }

       pool.shutdown(); // without this the main application will be blocked forever
   }

   private static boolean doPost(int t) {
       System.out.printf("%s: Post_%s%n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), t);

       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: This is what I discovered elsewhere as well. Forgot to come back and update the question again. So answer hereby accepted :)