# instance of CompletableFuture cannot get expected result

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

```
    CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("enter into completableFuture()");
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("start to out of completableFuture()");
        return "a";
    });

    System.out.println("do something else");

    cf1.thenApply(v -> v + " b").thenAcceptAsync(v ->
            System.out.println(v)
    );

    System.out.println("finalize...");

    //cannot get expected result, if this line was comment out.
    //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
```

code as above.

when writing a example of using CompletableFuture in jdk8, I got confused.

I must add the last line

`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);`

to get the expected result.

I would like to know whether the program has ended if I do not let its main thread to sleep. if not, why I cannot get the output?

really thanks for you time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Futures not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342302/nested-futures-not-executing)

Comment: Also [Why is CompletableFuture.supplyAsync succeeding a random number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439198/why-is-completablefuture-supplyasync-succeeding-a-random-number-of-times) (no answer there though)

Comment: thanks, I am going to review the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JVM terminates when no non-daemon threads are running, so if asynchronous operations are executed by daemon threads only, it will terminate when the main thread terminates, not continuing the background operations.

There are several ways to solve this.

1. If the background computations form a single dependency chain, you can use the last operation to wait for its completion, as its completion implies the completion of all previous stages. Letting the main thread wait until the completion defers the JVM’s termination to that point:

   ```
   CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       System.out.println("enter into completableFuture()");
       LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
       System.out.println("start to out of completableFuture()");
       return "a";
   });
   System.out.println("do something else");
   CompletableFuture last
       = cf1.thenApply(v -> v + " b").thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
   System.out.println("finalize...");
   last.join();
   ```
2. Consider the [documentation of `CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

   > All *async* methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) (unless it does not support a parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is created to run each task).

   Since it’s the property of that F/J common pool to use daemon threads, we can use that knowledge to wait for the completion of all pending tasks in that case, which works independently of the dependencies between these pending tasks:

   ```
   CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       System.out.println("enter into completableFuture()");
       LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
       System.out.println("start to out of completableFuture()");
       return "a";
   });
   System.out.println("do something else");
   cf1.thenApply(v -> v + " b").thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
   System.out.println("finalize...");
   if(ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism()>1)
       ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
   ```
3. Use an explicit executor, which will not use daemon threads. The thread pool executors provided by the JRE, letting `ForkJoinPool` aside, use non-daemon threads by default:

   ```
   final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
   CompletableFuture cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       System.out.println("enter into completableFuture()");
       LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
       System.out.println("start to out of completableFuture()");
       return "a";
   }, threadPool);
   System.out.println("do something else");
   cf1.thenApply(v -> v + " b").thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
   System.out.println("finalize...");
   threadPool.shutdown();
   ```

   Note that `threadPool.shutdown();` does not imply waiting nor does it stop pending tasks; it only stops accepting new tasks and ensures that the pooled threads will terminate once all pending tasks have been processed. You could place it directly after using it with `supplyAsync`, without changing the behavior.

   So the third solution is the only one letting the `main` thread exit, with the JVM continuing until all pending background tasks are processed, as they are running in non-daemon threads.

Comment: I might misunderstand the usage of class CompletableFuture. But your answer really help me to further be familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can suspend a `CompletableFuture` until completed by [CompletableFuture#join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--), for example:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> stage = cf1.thenApply(v -> v + " b").thenAcceptAsync(v ->
        System.out.println(v)
);

System.out.println("finalize...");

//   v--- the main thread wait until the stage is completed
stage.join();
```

Comment: but join() is a blocking method.. it is not my expected.

Comment: @MarcoJan if you don't blocking the main thread you maybe can't see the expected result when the program process exit. since `CompletableFuture` using an `Executor` to execute itself.

Comment: While the main thread exited, the CompletableFuture ended correspondingly, or continuously proceeding? if it continued, whether get expected result does not matter.

Comment: or, maybe I could start another thread to wrap CompletableFutre to do real business, it does not blocking my main thread. is it a proper solution?

Comment: @MarcoJan hi, when the process is exit, the uncompleted `CompletableFuture` is aborted.

Comment: @MarcoJan start another thread? you will resulting the same problem. since an `Executor` is a thread pool.

Comment: I mean I start another thread to wrap completablefuture and join to wait. it seems that the thread will not blocking my main thread.

Comment: @MarcoJan it is unnecessary and redundant. since you must blocking a daemon thread in the main thread too, or if your thread is not a daemon thread you must suspend the `CompletableFuture` in your thread too.

Comment: @MarcoJan not at all.

Comment: @holi-java: wrapping the operation in a non-daemon thread *would* work, but is unnecessary as `CompletableFuture` allows to specify an arbitrary executor, so it’s possible to run the background tasks in non-daemon threads in the first place.

Comment: @Holger yes, sir. I have already mentioned that in previous comments . maybe my bad english confused you, I'm sorry. :)