# thanAccept() does not print the value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I am learning CompletableFuture, in the following snippet the `thenAccept()` method does not print the value which should be `10`, but the program compiles without exception. Can anyone explain me what's the problem ?

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CompletableFutureTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureTest::counting).thenAccept(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("xD");
    }
    public static int counting() {


        Stream.iterate(1, integer -> integer +1).limit(5).forEach(System.out::println);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 10;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also [instance of CompletableFuture cannot get expected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540862/instance-of-completablefuture-cannot-get-expected-result)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `CompletableFuture` start working with main thread and after finished main thread your application finished.

You need waiting for `CompletableFuture` to finish.
You can do it:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureTest::counting)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println)
        .get();
```

Method `get()` waits if necessary for this future to complete