# Why is my Thread.sleep ending my process when inside a CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to create a CompleteableFuture. I am just trying to log out a few statements. Here is my code:

```
    static CompletableFuture<String> createFuture(String name) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("Task execution started.");
                //Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Task execution stopped.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return name;
        });
    }

    static void start(Person person, List<Person> people) {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
            createFuture("Bob")
        ).thenApply(s -> {
            return s;
        }).exceptionally(e -> {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        });
    }
```

Everything works fine, until I uncomment `Thread.sleep(2000)`. When uncommented, the process dies. It doesn't go into the `catch` and it doesn't go into the `exceptionally`. Why? What am I missing? How do I make this work?

Comment: Why do you expect the controller to go to `catch` block ?

Comment: I don’t. I just put it there to see if it was catching anything.

Comment: I suspect your program is exiting without waiting for the CompletableFuture to finish.  Try adding a call to [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join%28%29) or [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get%28%29) to the end of your `start` method.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540862/instance-of-completablefuture-cannot-get-expected-result

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` uses the common `JoinForkPool` to execute the supplier when an executor is not otherwise defined. As pointed out by user VGR in the question comments, the application is not waiting for the tasks to complete - this is because the threads in a JoinForkPool are all daemons, meaning that they do not block the application from shutting down while they're running.

The solution is to use the version of `supplyAsync` that takes an `Executor` and use a non-`JoinForkPool` executor so the threads are not daemons or get the common pool and do something to cause the pool to wait, such as the `awaitTermination` method.