# Thread is forever parked after sleep, spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpool, thread-sleep

I created a async configurer to make async methods, like this:

```
package backendApplication;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        return executor;
    }

}
```

And then defined my async method:

```
package backendApplication.model;


import backendApplication.model.dao.TourService;
import backendApplication.model.entities.Scheduling;
import backendApplication.model.entities.Tour;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;


@Service
public class SwapManager {

    @Autowired
    TourService tourService;

    @Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture addSchedule(Scheduling scheduling){
        long finishesIn = scheduling.getDate().getTime() - new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println(finishesIn);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(finishesIn);
            Tour t = scheduling.getTour();
            t.removeActive(scheduling);
            t.addFinished(scheduling);
            tourService.save(t);
            System.out.println("completou o schedule");
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }


}
```

And i call my async method in a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createScheduling/{idTour}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> createSchedulings(@PathVariable(value="idTour") String id, @RequestBody List<Scheduling> schedulings) {
        try{
            // Get tour
            Tour tour = tourService.get(Integer.parseInt(id));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(schedulings.toArray()));
            for (Scheduling s : schedulings){
                // Associate tour and save scheduling
                s.setPaid(true);
                s.setTour(tour);
                schedulingService.save(s);

                // Save scheduling active on tour
                tour.addActive(s);
                tourService.save(tour);

                // Add schedule to swap manager
                System.out.println("Adicionou schedule");
                swapManager.addSchedule(s);
            }

        }catch (Exception ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<> (HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<> (HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

But after the sleep time the thread passes from java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping) to java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking) without executing the code below the Thread.sleep() line.

**Can someone explain me why?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my Thread.sleep ending my process when inside a CompletableFuture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763910/why-is-my-thread-sleep-ending-my-process-when-inside-a-completablefuture)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, it as something to do with the fact that im using async annotation and CompletableFuture. I changed the return type to void and all seems to work well.